# How can open .plist file as source code xcode 11 beta 5

Tags: info.plist, xcode11

In new xcode 11 beta 5 there is no option to open .plist file as source code. Anyone know how can show this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I've found so far is to click on the plist in the project navigator, then click on the "Show or hide code review" icon in the toolbar.  That's this icon:

[image: Toolbar icon of arrows facing left and right]

Now you can edit the XML.  Hope that helps.

Comment: The "Editor Configuration Buttons" used to have different sub-modes. In this new button, it seems to always display the file in side-by-side / diff view. Can it be changed to plain-old-file view?

Answer (score 2):

The option is still there in Xcode 11, Xcode 11.4 beta & Xcode 12.2.

[image]